# Definitions intersection WPF control with the other

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, controls, intersection

The aim is this: determine the intersection of of the visual object with others, including children and return them in a convenient list, please help is very necessary. In short everything in the picture below illustrates:

[image]

Comment: Did you try firstControl.Clip.FillContainsWithDetail(secondControl.Clip) ? Which returns if an element contains another one, does or doesn't intersect

Comment: you do not incorrectly understood, I need it just returned objects which crossed, I do not need to highlight the intersection, I drew people to understand what objects should be returned :))))

Comment: it doesn't draw anything as far as I know: "Returns a value that describes the intersection between the current geometry and the specified geometry." It just return a IntersectionDetail that describes the interaction between geometries